# Is there any way to include special characters(#) as redirect uri in Googles API Manager(https://console.developers.google.com)

Tags: angularjs, google-plus, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I'm a node js developer. I'm in a way of authenticating and authorizing **Google** and **OpenOffice 365** using **OAuth2**. My projects' client side is angular js and I have a '#' in my url . But I can't given it as a redirect uri in my Google  or open365 (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) app registration console. The appications' validation says the special character is not valid. Is there way of solving this issue like encoding or something. Any help would be grateful. I'm also attaching a screen shot of the above.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2):

The redirect URL must be a true URL having a # in your url is called a "Fragment".

If you read the gray area.

> "can not contain url **fragments** or relative paths can not be IP
>   address"

Answer: As stated in the note on the Google Developer console Redirect URIs can not contain Fragments (#). There is no work around for this.